# TFS 2015 query to retrieve Test Plan results

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

Is there a way to create ordinary TFS query via Web interface and not API call or custom coding to get list of `Test Cases` (or it should be `Tests`) with `Outcome` column?

What should be the `Work Item Type` value in this case?

[image: TFS Test Plan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be achieved for now. You can't do it just from workitem query.

Since *TFS 2013 Update 3* test plans and test suites are regular work items, but there are of no practical use in work item queries, as **there are no links between them and test cases.**

With the links, you could create a query to list all test cases in a specified test plan. There has been a feature request in ***uservoice***, you can also vote up for it to get more attention.

> **Support querying for "all test cases in a specifed test plan" a.k.a add work item links between test plans, test suites and test cases**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12457410-support-querying-for-all-test-cases-in-a-specifed

Comment: Thank you, it's annoying though)